# Delete with criteria API?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

Let's say I have a criteria

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Foo> {

    static Specification<Foo> byBars(Collection<String> bars) {
        return (Root<Foo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (bars.isEmpty()) {
                return criteriaBuilder.disjunction();
            }

            return root.get("bar").in(bars);
        };
    }
}
```

Alright, that gives us `fooRepository.findAll(byBars(...) )`

Now how do I define a repository method to achieve a bulk delete?

```
deleteBy(Specification<Foo> specification);
```

doesn't work, neither do

```
void deleteAll(Specification<Foo> specification);
```

or

```
void delete(Specification<Foo> specification);
```

because

> No property deleteBy found for type Foo!

Answer (score 0):

Spring specification has support for find, findAll and count query.
There is no support for delete and update methods in spring-data JPA.

Reference from **JpaSpecificationExecutor**:

```
Optional<T> findOne(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);

List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);

Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);

List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Sort sort);

long count(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);
```